# django_cron executes only once, scheduler not working?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework, django-redis

I have to implement task on schedule , for that i am using django_cron.
 In setting :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'mailsnake',
    'corsheaders',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Avaana_web',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'django_cron',

]
```

and cron.py

```
    from django_cron import CronJobBase, Schedule,cronScheduler
    import datetime,os
    class MyCronJob(CronJobBase):
        RUN_EVERY_MINS = .3
        RETRY_AFTER_FAILURE_MINS = 5
        ALLOW_PARALLEL_RUNS = True
        schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS,      
  retry_after_failure_mins=RETRY_AFTER_FAILURE_MINS)
        code = 'my_app.my_cron_job'
        def do(self):
            print("hello")
```

but when i run

```
$ python manage.py runcrons
 hello
```

Only once output shows and ends.

> How i can get output after every 30 seconds.

Comment: i have also install django_cron. via
$ pip install django_cron

Comment: try running with `python -u manage.py runcrons`

Comment: read #6 from this link http://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: how to use `django_cron` for sending email after every 30 min.
on view

Comment: My cron.py contains :

`from django_cron import CronJobBase, Schedule, get_class
 from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
class my_scheduled_job(CronJobBase):
 RUN_EVERY_MINS = 30
 schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS)
 print("schedule")
 print(schedule)

 code = 'Sana_web.my_cron_job'
 
 def do(self):
  email = EmailMessage('title', 'body', to=[email])
  email.send()
`

Answer (score 1):

a couple of things:

a. looks like your cron job isn't configured properly. according to doc, you need to create a CRON_CLASSES list in your settings path points to fully-qualified package name of your cron class, like this:

```
CRON_CLASSES = [
    "my_app.cron.MyCronJob",
    # ...
]
```

b. also, the point of running it via python manage doesn't mean it'll continue to run multiple times. you probably still need to run the 'python manage.py runcrons' from a cron job. your schedule will merely decide whether it *needs* to run when you call manage.py runcrons. see more much detail here: http://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html